# CSS Div Positioning 4 divs

Tags: css

```
<div class="div1">required styles applied</div>
<div class="div2">required styles applied</div>
<div class="div1">required styles applied</div>
<div class="div2">required styles applied</div>
```

[image]
My code appears like in figure 1. But I want to transform it to second. How can I do that ?

Comment: Maybe Bootstrap grid system: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flexbox` and `order` the third item to be the second.

[**Example**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojKQrO?editors=110)

Code:

```
container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-around;
}

.div1,.div2 {
  background:green;
  text-align: center;
  color:#fff;
  width: 48%;
}

.div1 {
  min-height: 120px;
  margin: 30px 0px;
  line-height: 120px;
}

.div2 {
  min-height: 250px;
  line-height: 250px;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  order:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a column approach -this keeps the divs in their original order:

```
<!DOCTYPE: html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Four divs</title>
<style type="text/css">

html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

.columnate
{
    height: 100%;

    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* older webkit */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;

    -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    column-gap: 1em;

    padding: 1em
}

.div1,
.div2
{
    height: 30%;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin: 0px auto 1em auto;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
}

.div2
{
    height: 50%;
}

.div2:nth-of-type(1)
{
    break-after: column;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="columnate">
    <div class="div1">required styles applied</div>
    <div class="div2">required styles applied</div>
    <div class="div1">required styles applied</div>
    <div class="div2">required styles applied</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a very strong advocate of using bootstrap in this situation.
All you need is to resource is 2 lines of code.

```
<style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css></style>
<script type="text/javascript" https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js></script>
```

Then i just surrounded the divs with bootstrap columns like so:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="div1">required styles applied</div>
    <div class="div2">required styles applied</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="div1">required styles applied</div>
    <div class="div2">required styles applied</div>
</div>
```

Then added some styles so you could see how they look.

```
.div1 {
    width: 100%;
    background: #EBEBEB;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.div2 {
    width: 100%;
    background: #506ACA;
    height: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

The great thing about this is it is short and sweet, not difficult to understand, and will be ready for mobile resolutions also.

Check out this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/msechrest/jwka7gax/) to see what I mean.

[Here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) is a link to learning Bootstrap if you are interested in using this framework.

Hope this helped!